# InverseSeries slower than it should be

Tags: inverse

I am running into problems with InverseSeries taking far longer than it should. Given (for example)

$$F = q + a_2 q^2 + a_3 q^3 + \ldots + a_{99} q^{99} + O(q^{100}),$$

Computing the inverse series is an easy inductive procedure; you start with $h =q + O(q^2)$; then once you have computed $h = q + b_2 q^2 + \ldots b_{n-1} q^{n-1} + O(q^n)$ you write

$$F(q + \ldots + b_n q^n) = q  +  b_n q^n + (\text{some integer})q^n + O(q^{n+1})$$

and then you immediately solve for $b_n$. The most expensive part of this calculation is substituting a degree $d < 100$ polynomial into another degree $d < 100$ polynomial, which is annoying, but is something that mathematica can do quickly. But somehow whatever the code for InverseSeries does it freezes on examples that I can do faster "by hand", where  "by hand" means repeating the procedure above. What is going wrong, and how can it be fixed?

Here is an example which I can do manually in a few minutes but which Mathematica freezes on: (apologies I just cut and paste and I'm not sure of the correct formatting)

**edit:** In the original post, I wrote out the explicit form of $F$. As @CarlWoll pointed out, that seems to run in a second or two. So I modified it to give the example below. Here $F$ is first computed from scratch (this is exactly the same $F$ as before), mathematica now hangs --- hopefully others can reproduce this. This now now especially strange, since one could just output $F$ then quit then compute InverseSeries. (Computing $F$ only takes a few seconds.) **end edit:**

```
eta[q_] := q^(1/24) Product[(1 - q^n), {n, 1, 101}];
f := f = eta[q^3] eta[q^33]/(eta[q] eta[q^11]) + O[q]^101;
F := F = 1/((-11 + (1 + 3*f)^2*(1/f + 1 + 3*f)));
InverseSeries[F]
```

Comment: Did you mean `InverseSeries[F + O[q]^101]`? If so, that takes about 1 second on my computerr.

Comment: @CarlWoll Apologies, that is exactly what I meant. I modified my question (or rather, changed the definition of F to F = q + ... + O[q]^101. And "about 1 second" is roughly what  I would expect too. Possibly my computer is having memory issues or maybe my Mathematica version is out of date?

Comment: Using Version 10.4.1.0 on MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015), BTW.

Comment: I tried using 10, 10.3 and 11.1 on a 2015 MacBook Pro, and they all took about a second. What happens if you try the code from a fresh kernel?

Comment: 0.8 seconds on an aging laptop, 12.1.1 on Win10...

Comment: @CarlWoll holy moly, that worked! But this has been happening to me all the time recently (although in the middle of other computations rather than right after restarting the kernel). Before this point lots of other numbers have been saved and computed, so maybe that means it's a memory thing...

Comment: @CarlWoll OK now I can reproduce the problem; question edited.

Comment: Computing `F` takes forever on my machine. If I change your second line to: `f := f = Assuming[q>0, eta[q^3] eta[q^33]/(eta[q] eta[q^11]) + O[q]^101]` then everything is quick. Also, why not use [`QPochhammer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QPochhammer)?

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks again. Computing $F$ (or $f$) by any method is quick for me. I think my comment under the answer below explains my confusion. Apologies for the repeated comments...

Comment: The point is, that `Series ` (initiated with `O[q]^101 `) does not expand the eta and therefore assumes q^(1/24) to be the lowest term. If you do `f//FullForm ` or `F//FullForm ` you see, it produced a series object that is 24 times larger than 101 with a lot of zero points. A workaround is the way @Samos proposed or simpliy reduce the blown up series data object with `Normal ` and then add `O[q]^101`  Do `InverseSeries[Normal[F] + O[q]^101] ` is as fast as you expect.

Comment: @CarlWoll -- ah, that explains it completely. The two outputs I *thought* were the same are in fact quite different, as you point out. BTW, I liked using eta[q] rather than something like QPochhammer because it has an error correction for typos --- if I put in the wrong exponents it most likely will be a power series in q^(1/24) rather than one I know starts as q + .... But I know see that comes at a terrible cost! (well, not that terrible). Let me thank you again for persisting with my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are computing way too many series terms with `eta[]`. Here is my slightly modified code:

```
eta[k_] := q^(k/24) Product[1-q^n, {n,k,101,k}];
f = eta[3]eta[33]/(eta[1]eta[11]) + O[q]^101;
F = 1/((-11 + (1 + 3*f)^2*(1/f + 1 + 3*f)));
InverseSeries[F]
```

It should have **much** better performance than yours.

Comment: Thanks; I agree that is a better implementation to compute $F$. But it's not computing $F$ that's the problem, it's computing InverseSeries[F]. Why should the computation of F (once it's done) make any difference to how long InverseSeries[F] takes?

Comment: Computing $F$ your way is almost instantaneous, whereas computing it my way takes about $5$ seconds. But since the output is exactly the same, I don't understand why InverseSeries[F] then fails with my output but is pretty quick with mine.

Comment: Ah, as explained in the comments by @CarlWoll above, the outputs are *not*  "exactly the same" as I claimed, as there is hidden extra (useless) information in my computation.  So now this question is resolved (for me).